# How can one pasteurize beer at home?

Tags: brewing

Pasteurizing is a common task at industrial brewers. But in a home brewing context following questions arises:

- Is it feasible to pasteurize in the kitchen?
- Which equipment is necessary to do it?
- What are the best-practices of such process?
- Is there a risk of degrading the overall taste of the beer?

Comment: FYI: We also have a site dedicated to [Homebrew.SE].

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about homebrewing. Homebrew questions should be directed to [homebrew.se]

Comment: Silly me, i have mistakenly posted on this page instead of Homebrewing. Is there a way to move this post?

Comment: @JavaCake: Since we are still in private beta, no.  But if and when the site goes public, we can.  In the meantime, you can either wait or re-ask over on that site.

Comment: Just for the record, my answer (as one who has been homebrewing for almost 2 decades) is the best practice is not to.  Sterilize your bottles and equipment.  Once you start pasteurizing, you are going to have lots of extra stuff you have to do and there are risks of having all kinds of additional things going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

To do this, you should have a thermometer that you can throw into the water to measure the temperature, a pot for boiling water, and some bottles of beer.

1. Boil the water.
2. When the water reaches 190 degrees Fahrenheit, turn off the water.
3. Carefully put the bottles into the pit.
4. Put the lid on the pot and wait about ten minutes.
5. Carefully remove the bottles with a kitchen tong (or a mitten).
6. Put them on the counter to cool until they reach room temperature.
7. Refrigerate them.

Remember that the bottles are pressurized, so don't bang them while putting them in the pot, don't apply heat to the pot while the bottles are in there, etc.